# OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceContract>

Tags: performance, wcf

In WCF, I'm able to use this call to get the service contract and then in that service contract I can invoke a method which calls back the client.  Ok fine.

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceContract>
```

But, ultimately, this is just a bare bones service contract.  The method named "GetCallbackChannel" indicates to me that a Channel object should be returned here.  You know, a channel object that has a state property such as Closed, Open, etc, as well as events for state change.

WCF sure makes it difficult to grab the async channel that it is keeping open for the Async call.  How else can I grab this channel?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer.  I had tried something similar, but providing the CommunicationObject type in the GetCallbackChannel didn't work.  Casting it to ICommuicationObject after getting the channel does work.

```
        var c = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceContract>();
        ICommunicationObject chan = (ICommunicationObject)c;
```